# passing intent from Activity to Service fails

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I'm trying to pass intent information from an Activity to a Service but it doesn't work.

Before startService(), I add extras to the intent.
When executing startService(), the service tries to obtain the extras but the pointer is null

here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    final ToggleButton btnPlayStop = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlayStop);
    btnPlayStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class);
            intent.putExtra("song", "umake");
            /*
                Debugger displays:
                    intent.mExtras.mMap.table[1]
                        key = "song"
                        value = "umake"
             */

            startService(intent);
        }
    }
}

public class MyService extends Service
{
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    try
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       // intent = getIntent();                 
       // --> compiler error: The method getIntent() is undefined for the type MyService

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String song = extras.getString("song");  // nope

        song = intent.getStringExtra("song");  // nope
        Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("song");  // nope
        song = bundle.getString("song");  // nope

        /*
            Neither of the above works since the map in extras is null
            Debugger displays:
                intent.mExtras.mMap == null

            whereas before startService is was filled all right
         */
    }...
```

It is as if the data got 'lost' during the startService.
how to solve this?

thank you

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Try these code in service

```
 String song=intent.getStringExtra("song");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you didn't get the string value in the bundle.
try to add extras.getString("")

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
String song = intent.getBundleExtra("song");
```

Comment: intent.getBundleExtra("song") is defined as returning something of type Bundle instead of String
Am I using a wrong/deprecated API?
What API are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In your **MainActivity.java**, where you declare your intent, Try having

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MyService.class);
```

Then Receiving your intent in **MyService.java**, Try having

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
  try
  {
      Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      intent = getIntent(); //Here You Want to make sure you are actually getting values from the previous activity
      Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    /*
        Debugger displays:
            intent.mExtras.mMap == null
     */
}
```

I don't think you were intializing your intent properly, that's why it kept giving you that error

Comment: @ChrisPeeters Accept Answer if this Code worked for you, if not tell me what errors i have here

Comment: intent = getIntent()
 doesn't work for me  
  --> "The method getIntent() is undefined for the type MyService"